# What is a small white grub-like larva destroying my huchera?

Tags: pests

Trying to identify small white larvae that is killing plants like [huchera](http://heucheras.com/). It is about 1/4" long with legs on its front half.  Hates light. Very mushy. When squeezed it has no color.

Comment: Did you try throwing some wood ash on the plants?
Have a picture?

Comment: I don't suppose there's any chance of a picture of the grub? Be useful if you could provide one, but also, where are you in the world and are these plants in pots or in the ground? Did you find the grub in the soil or on top of the soil?